# How do I create a string whose `puts` output is `cote \d'ivoire`?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, literals

I don't know how to create a string `var` whose `puts` output would be:

```
cote \d'ivoire
```

I tried:

```
var = "cote \d'ivoire"
```

whose output is:

```
puts var 
#=> cote d'ivoire
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the backslash with a backslash:

```
var = "cote \\d'ivoire"
```

Comment: [HHK](http://www.amazon.com/Happy-Hacking-Keyboard-Professional2-Black/dp/B000EXZ0VC) at work again!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\`

```
2.1.2-perf :004 > var="cote \\d'ivoire"
 => "cote \\d'ivoire"
2.1.2-perf :005 > puts var
cote \d'ivoire
```

Comment: thx a lot. I was confused by the output during the var affectation. I did not have a try with puts

Comment: @stefancervo you can accept the answer that helped you by clicking the big check mark beside the answer.